# Google Apps Script IF trigger Push to Slack

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, webhooks, slack

I have a google sheet that interactive to-do list tied together with dates, and if one of the dates goes past due it copies over to a separate tab within the sheet called 'Past'. I use the code below to push these Past Due Alerts into a Slack channel with a daily setup Google Apps Trigger, but what I want to do is add in an IF variable that would only post if there was a row in that tab to post. For example, if A2=""then don't push to slack, if A2=Not Blank push to slack. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here is the code I'm working with:

```
 function createMeetingMessage(sheet) {
 var facilitatorCell = "Past!C2";
 var noteTakerCell = "Past!E2";
 var emojiCell = "Past!L2";
var message = "> *Hello* "  + "<" +sheet.getRange(noteTakerCell).getValue() +">" + " *Please Update Us On*\n"
+ "> *Task:* " +sheet.getRange(facilitatorCell).getValue() +"\n"
+ "> *Due Date:* " +sheet.getRange(emojiCell).getValue() +"\n"
+ "> _you can submit an update by typing task;task name;in progress or complete; comments_ ";

 return message;
}

function triggerSlackRequest(channel, msg) {
 var slackWebhook = "[Slack Webhook]";
  var payload = { "channel": channel, "text": msg, "link_names": 1, "username": "Past Due Alert", "icon_emoji": ":rotating_light:" };
 var options = { "method": "post", "contentType": "application/json", "muteHttpExceptions": true, "payload": JSON.stringify(payload) };

Logger.log(UrlFetchApp.fetch(slackWebhook, options));
}

function notifySlackChannelOfFacilitatorAndNoteTaker() {
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Past");
 var channel = getChannel();

var msg = createMeetingMessage(sheet);
 triggerSlackRequest(channel, msg);
}

function isTest() {
 return false;
}

function getChannel() {
 if(isTest()) {
 return "integration_tests";
 } else {
 return "integration_tests";
 }
}
```

And here is what it looks like when there is data in A2 when pushed to Slack:
[image]

And then here is what it looks like when there isn't data in A2 and it pushed to Slack:
[image]

Thanks!

Comment: If you don't want to run the script when "A2" in a sheet of "Past" has no value, you can achieve it by putting ``if (!sheet.getRange("A2").getValue()) return`` before ``var channel = getChannel()``. But I'm not sure whether this is what you want to do. So if this was not what you want, in order to understand correctly what you want to do, can you explain it using a sample spreadsheet?

Comment: @Tanaike this worked perfectly! Thank you much! Looks like this now: `function notifySlackChannelOfFacilitatorAndNoteTaker() {
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Past");
 if (!sheet.getRange("B2").getValue()) return;
var channel = getChannel();`

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was solved. Can you post it as an answer and accept it? By this, it will be useful for users who have the same issue.

Comment: @Tanaike Done. Thank you again for your help!!!

Comment: Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to run the script when "A2" in a sheet of "Past" has no value, you can achieve it by putting if `(!sheet.getRange("A2").getValue()) return` before `var channel = getChannel()`. Worked perfectly!